# Meteor pushing data from client to server using DDP

Tags: javascript, meteor, backend, ddp

I am planning to write a meteor/DDP server for a strongly typed, data-driven backend platform. The server must be able to both push data to, and accept data from a client.

After reading the [DDP documentation](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/ddp/DDP.md) it seems the protocol only supports client-side subscriptions on data. From the document, I don't see how meteor pushes data back from a client to a server.

The document states DDP supports "Remote procedure calls by the client to the server.". I suppose I could define C(R)UD procedures for pushing modifications back to the server, but I'm afraid I'd deviate from the native Meteor experience.

Any suggestions are appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ah yes this is probably less clear.

When you run a `insert`, `update`, `remove` or `upsert` operation this actually triggers `method`. The DDP protocol doesn't directly take CRUD operations.

The method names would be as follows for an insert into a collection called 'mycollection'

Method name : `/mycollection/insert`

the params would be the document itself as the first parameter with an optional `randomSeed` parameter.

Example JSON to insert a document `{ name: "bob", email: "bob@bob.bob"}`

`{"msg":"method","method":"/mycollection/insert","params":[{ _id:"123456", name: "bob", email: "bob@bob.bob"}],"id":"1"}`

Likewise, `update` using `update` instead of `insert` in the path, i.e `/mycollection/update` gives in two params with an optional third containing options.

Comment: So, this added,changed,removed changes push to a ddp connection server cannot be done ? Or if there is any way please do share the code snippet if possible.